# Video embed code verification

Tags: security, video

I have a website where the user is able to add a youtube,vimeo etc. embed code.
How can i verify if that the code submitted links really to a video and i don't risk the security of my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the format of the embed code is known, it would be simple for you to extract the data identifying the video clip and use that inside *your own* templated copy of the embed code. Just insert the video clip identifier in your template.